# add raw to res dir

Tags: java, android, eclipse, r.java-file

I know this is a well-known problem
but I did every possible thing:

1. cleaned the project
2. re-build
3. remove the project and add again.

but still.
the R file does not updated

what do you suggest me to do?

thanks
socksocket

Comment: Go to "Windows --> Show View --> Problems (or errors, etc.)" and make sure there aren't errors preventing your project from building.

Comment: Please give some more details.. like was it already working earlier and stopped after you made some changes.. if yes, tell us the changes you did. Also, paste here the error which is shown in the 'Problems' view and we may be able to help you...

Comment: @AlexLockwood - no errors. I can build my project

Comment: @Mahendra - the Raw folder was not exist so I added it.
but it doesn't get updated in the R file..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. found the solution
I had sub-directory inside "raw" directory and I think it is forbidden for some reason
I moved the mp3 files to "raw" dir and removed the sub-dir called "sounds"

and now it works!
cheers!

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure that you have chosen the appropriate target build settings from the project properties
- Cross-check the platform versions with the layouts you have used in your app
- Remove import statements such as `import android.R.*;`